# CarrierWave image uploader - POST request sends the correct parameters but image saves image as "image":{"url":null}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

PROBLEM:
I'm trying to make a POST request for Visions. It has two parameters both of which are being passed. However, it saves in this format (and image url is always 'null'):

```
{"data":{"user":{"id":26,"image":{"url":null},"description":"dsfsfdsfdsfsd"}}}
```

What do I need to do to save the image parameter that I'm passing, as the url string within the image object?

**This is my Visions table:**

```
class CreateVisions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :visions do |t|
      t.string :image
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**VisionsController.rb:**

```
 def create
  @vision = current_user&.visions.build(vision_params)
  @vision.save
  render :create, status: :created
 end

 def vision_params
  params.require(:vision).permit(:image, :description)
 end
```

**vision.json.jbuilder:**

```
json.call(
    vision,
    :id,
    :image,
    :description
)
```

**User Modal:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :trackable, :rememberable, :validatable


  has_many :posts
  has_many :visions
end
```

**Vision model:**

```
class Vision < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

I'm making my POST request like this:

```
let response = await fetch('https://prana-app.herokuapp.com/v1/visions/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-User-Email': this.state.email,
                'X-User-Token': this.state.accessToken
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              vision: {
                description: 'dsfsfdsfdsfsd',
                image: this.state.uploadFile
              }
            })
        });
```

when I make the request, it receives the parameters as so:

```
Parameters: {"vision"=>{"description"=>"dsfsfdsfdsfsd", "image"=>"file:///BLABLABLA.jpg"}}
```

Comment: Please add `visin_params` method  and User model in question

Comment: @Vishal added vision_params and user modal information :)

Comment: if you want to store image, why you take data type as string ?

Comment: @vishal because that's what all the tutorials are telling me to do

Comment: I think you should use paperclip for uploading files, even better if you active storage of ruby on rails itself.